# Re-Render Index View from Partial View within Index view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

There is the Index View with a partial view for pagination.
The _pagination partial view calls the Index ActionResult in the main Controller if the button btnRowsPerPage is clicked. 
The contoller method is called with the correct variables but the view (Index) is not updated. What do I miss?

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_Pagination", new { offset = ViewBag.Offset, take = ViewBag.Take, count = ViewBag.Count } )
</div>
```

Static integration of the partial view in Index view.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
<li class="page-item @(ViewBag.Offset==0 ? "disabled" : "")">
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { po = 0, sk = ViewBag.Take }, new { @class = "page-link" })
</li>
<li class="page-item @(ViewBag.PageCount==0 ? "disabled" : "")">
    @Html.ActionLink("<", "Index", new { po = ViewBag.Offset == 0 ? 0 : ViewBag.Offset - 1, sk = ViewBag.Take }, new { @class = "page-link" })
</li>
@for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.PageCount; i++) {
    <li class="page-item @(ViewBag.Offset==i ? "active" : "")">
        @Html.ActionLink((i + 1).ToString(), "Index", new { po = i, sk = ViewBag.Take }, new { @class = "page-link" })
    </li>
}
<li class="page-item @(ViewBag.Offset==ViewBag.PageCount ? "disabled" : "")">
    @Html.ActionLink(">", "Index", new { po = ViewBag.Offset == ViewBag.PageCount ? ViewBag.Offset : ViewBag.Offset + 1, sk = ViewBag.Take }, new { @class = "page-link" })
</li>
<li class="page-item @(ViewBag.Offset==ViewBag.PageCount ? "disabled" : "")">
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { po = (int)(ViewBag.PageCount), sk = ViewBag.Take }, new { @class = "page-link" })
</li>
<li class="page-item">
    <input class="col-sm-5" type="number" placeholder="@ViewBag.Take" id="RowsPerPageValue" />
</li>
<li class="page-item" id="RowsPerPageLi">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateRowsPerPage()" id="btnRowsPerPage">Requery</button>
</li>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var updateRowsPerPage = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TParts")',

            data: {
                po: @ViewBag.Offset,
                sk: $('#RowsPerPageValue').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Partial View with JavaScript

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? po, int? sk)
    {
        int offset = po ?? 0;
        int take = sk ?? 5;
        if(offset < 0) offset = 0;
        if(take < 1) take = 1;
        ViewBag.Take = take;
        int count = db.TParts.Count();
        ViewBag.PageCount = (int)(count / take) + ((count % take) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        if(offset > ViewBag.PageCount) offset = ViewBag.PageCount;
        ViewBag.Offset = offset;
        var tParts = db.TParts.Include(t => t.PartType).OrderBy(o => o.Title).Skip(offset * take).Take(take);
        return View(tParts.ToList());
    }
```

Index Method of the Main Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not handling the response from the server in you ajax call.

```
  <div id="page-details">
    @Html.Partial("_Pagination", new { offset = ViewBag.Offset, take = ViewBag.Take, count = ViewBag.Count } )
</div>
```

and then in your JS file

```
       $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TParts")',

            data: {
                po: @ViewBag.Offset,
                sk: $('#RowsPerPageValue').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#page-details').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this nearly is it! To get the correct Index view (with the correct amount of datasets declared in paging textbox) the <body> tag got the "page-details" id and the everything works fine. Thank you